# v-else is getting rendered first instead v-if in Vue JS

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vuejs-routing

I have an HTML element like below

```
<div v-if="showOriginalContent"> original content</div>
<div v-else> default content </div>
```

initial value of showOriginalContent is false
and from mounted method am calling an another method where i will make the value of showOriginalContent to true based on some conditions . Currently even if the showOriginalContent is true i can see that v-else is getting displayed for a fraction of seconds before v-if is rendered in the DOM .  How can i solve this issue ? I tried to move the function call to all other life cycle methods but nothing is working . I have gone through before and after navigation approach in vue js ,Is it possible to apply that logic here?

Comment: `Currently even if the showOriginalContent is true i can see that v-else is getting displayed for a fraction of seconds before v-if is rendered in the DOM` ...I don't believe you. Show more code..

Comment: Also pls make up your mind - you can not use [vuejs2] and [vuejs3] tags at the same time...

Comment: look into using [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) to hide your app until loaded, it sounds like vue is not loading before you render the html, causing both divs to show for a moment

Comment: is `showOriginalContent` reactive? a `data` or `computed`? If you could show us more of your code then we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal if I understood correctly what you posed as the problem.

Because the mounted state is called when the view has already been OK and displayed and only once.

So a variable declaring in this method its change will not necessarily have an effect on what should be displayed.

Try to see the `lifecycle` in Vuejs for more detail.

Put it in `computed or watch` methods to see.

Comment: What is worth saying that in the view the last value that it knows of this variable is `false`

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer `div` and control this div with another variable that will be `true` when you are done with your condition parts in mounted hook.. like this..

```
<div v-if="conditioncheckdone">
<div v-if="showOriginalContent"> original content</div>
<div v-else> default content </div>
</div>
```

It will resolve your issue of displaying `v-else` stuff while you are checking your conditions in mounted

Comment: I tried above solution but it is not working as expected . I think HTML template is getting rendered  before VUE life cycle is getting executed .

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure your original content is hidden by setting the value of `showOriginalContent` to something that is not `false`... say an empty string '' and show your content only if `showOriginalContent` is the boolean you expect like so. This way, the content will not show unless it is changed to either `true` or false on mounting. Someone correct me if it is against any best practices. Cheers.

```js
<div v-if="showOriginalContent===true"> original content</div>
<div v-if="showOriginalContent===false"> default content </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

turn the default showOriginalContent value to null instead of false